# Anything slider show multiple slides

Tags: jquery

I'm using anything slider, which is fantastic, but I'm just having a problem with getting the slider to show multiple slides.

This is the code that I've used:

```
jQuery(function(){
jQuery('#slider').anythingSlider({
showMultiple : 5
}); // add any non-default options here
});
```

Is this right? I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

... that is right. However, not enough to diagnose why it doesn't work. Did you get it to work without that option first? ... can you put it up on jsfiddle? ... sample of maybe 2 slides that you're trying to show? ... browser version? Need a bit more context/code.

Answer (score 0):

Realised that I needed to download the latest version of anythingslider, then it worked!

Here's a demo that was created for me by anythingslider, I'm very grateful:

http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Cm479/2818/